# Problem with color background in the render

Tags: rendering, light, eevee-render-engine, lighting, color

I have a scene with a sunlight and a color background, but when I render the scene I have a blue scene. Its is who the light sun was blue, but the light in the preferences is white. I rendered the scene with Eevee. And I need only the blue background without blue light. Please, I need to find the problem. I show the images, the first render is without background, and the other render is with blue background.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please don't use ALL CAPS, it is considered shouting and is rude

Comment: Why? I use ALL CAPS because is better for the view and it is more clear to read.

Comment: No its not https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing

Comment: .blend file please